# Two different ways of "catching" two different kinds of exceptions in C#. Is one better than another?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I've never had the need catch more than one exception at a time before. But here's my scenario. I want to "try" to copy a file. If the destination doesn't exist, I don't want to be bothered by it. But I DO still want to catch any other type of exception. A UnauthorizedAccessException for example. Below are two things I've tried, but I've seen both examples used on the web. Is one better coding than another. Or am I completly wrong on both? Thanks.

```
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

or

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is DirectoryNotFoundException)
            {
                // Do nothing
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: All very good comments. I'll know that in the future should the need arise, to go with the first block. But I shouldn't have needed this in the first place. Thanks to you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO, Having multiple catch will reduce the code-readability.  So this is what I would like to suggest.

```
if (Directory.Exists(dirPath))
        {
            try
            {
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile);
            }
            catch (Exception msg)
            {
                //Handle Exception.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Karthik. I should have thought of that.

Comment: You are most Welcome, Jim,  Cheers.

Comment: @pst is correct; this code now has an unavoidable race condition. If the directory exists when DirectoryExists returns, but it is deleted by another process just before File.Copy starts, then you still might get an exception. It's often not worth it to try and anticipate all possible "exogenous" exceptions; sometimes it is better to just catch the exception, deal with it, and move on.

Answer (score 4):

The first option is better form, but really they both work equally well.

Go with the first one, it makes for cleaner code

Comment: +1.  Cleaner code is always better and easier for someone else to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

One advice: **never** catch an exception which you do not intend to handle:

```
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    // Do Nothing
}
```

As far as your question is concerned, I would prefer the first approach (assuming of course you know what to do for each exception you have caught).

Comment: Are you criticizing this pattern because you think the code should be written to not throw, or criticizing it because you prefer the conditional?  I agree that it might be better to not throw, but you don't always control which exceptions might be coming out of your method.

Comment: I've read that too. So you're right Darrin. So I'm doing what Karthik suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the first one for 3 reasons:

1. It reads better (IMO).
2. I'd be concerned about the overhead of the `ex is DirectorNotFoundException` statement in the second.
3. The first one would also be easier to modify - what happens if you have to trap a 3rd type of exception, or a fourth, or...?

Just make sure you catch the exceptions in the right order.